# How Can I make setInterval countUp timer keep counting even in "Another Page" or "browser refresh"?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, session-storage

i try to create some "visitor CountUp timer" on my header webpage. However when I select another tab, the timer is restart again from 00:00:00. Is there any solution to make it keep counting even in "Another Page" or "browser refresh"? I am not sure how to add *sessionStorage* into my current code.

Anyone willing to lend a hand on this?

Thanks

```js
var sec = 0;
    function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
    setInterval( function(){
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60%60,10));
        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/3600%60,10));
    }, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="hours">00</span>:<span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>
```

Comment: If you are counting up, store the time you *started* counting in LocalStorage. Whenever the tab refeshes, see if there's a value in LocalStorage and based on this value calculate how long the timer should have been running.

Comment: sessionStorage is not a solution for you, because in each new tab the timer will be rested. localStorage is a good choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is using localstorage:

```
      var sec = 0;
      tmpSec = localStorage.getItem('secs')
      if (tmpSec != null) {
        sec = parseInt(tmpSec,10);
      }
      function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
      setInterval( function(){
        ++sec
        localStorage.setItem('secs', sec)
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(sec%60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60%60,10));
        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/3600%60,10));
      }, 1000);
```

Here is an example of interval which saved in localStorage https://github.com/syronz/micro-games/blob/master/02%20idle%20game/progress.html

Comment: Could you include the relevant details of how to do it in the answer itself? Link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: You're right, I'm update the answer based on his code. but the link just was a small file.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution! it solve my problem sir :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sec = 0;
```

that is going to reset your timer each time it is run.

But instead code it this way:

```
sessionStorage.sec = "0"; // only execute this when you want to reset your counter.

setInterval( function(){
  var sec = parseInt(sessionStorage.sec); 
  sec++;
  sessionStorage.sec = sec.toString();
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(sec%60);
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60%60,10));
  document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/3600%60,10));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a query to the URL and then redirect to another URL with this query:

```
window.location.href += "?end=someTime"
```

Then you could set the timer to have this as the end:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var end = url.searchParams.get("end");
doSomething(end);
```